# How to reference an another class with non _id field in typegoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

**I'm using Typegoose v9.3.1**

I need to create a reference for another collection with non **_id** field using **Typegoose**.

For example i'm having the following models.

**Class collection**

```
export class Class {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public _id!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public grade!: Source;

  @prop({ autopopulate: true, ref: Student, type: String })
  public students!: Ref<Student, string>[];
}
```

**Student Collection**

```
export class Student {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public rollNo!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public name!: string;
}
```

From the above example Class collection referencing the student collection based on the **_id** field (by default) of Student collection. But i need to create a reference based on the **rollNo** field(**non _id field**).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i know of for this case are virtual populates:

- [Mongoose: Virtual Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)
- [Typegoose: Virtual Populate](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/virtuals/#virtual-populate)

I am not aware of any method to change the field the prop-option `ref` uses, so i can only provide a virtual populate example.

Note: this example *may* not work in all cases, like if you have specific data layout requirements.

Example:

```
export class Class {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public _id!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public grade!: Source;

  @prop({ autopopulate: true, ref: () => Student, foreignField: "classId localField: "_id" })
  public students!: Ref<Student, string>[];
}

export class Student {
  @prop({ required: true, ref: () => Class }) // this could also be done without "ref" and just setting the type to "ObjectId"
  public classId: Ref<Class>;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public rollNo!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public name!: string;
}
```

If the above example does not work in your case, then i think your only option is to use a manual query / aggregation.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Tried and not working. will go with query/aggregation @hasezoey